# Getting a valueset around a specific values

Tags: python

say  I have the following value for `x = 0.5`

how can I get a array of values around it  something :

```
y = [-4,-2 -5 , 0.5 , 1 , 3, 6,8]
```

is there a python function that can do this , something :

```
radomaround(value, numberOfValuesBefor,numberofvaluesafter)
```

or `randomaround(value,numberofValues)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a very special case to me, so I guess you need to write yourself one:

```
import random

def randaround(value, low, hi, num=5):
    lower = [random.uniform(low, value) for _ in range(num)]
    higher = [random.uniform(value, hi) for _ in range(num)]
    return lower + [value] + higher
x = 0.5
print(randaround(x, -2, 4))
```

Outputs:

```
[0.33673180511496215, -1.2546042323682594, -0.681556151907607, 0.3568323009807952, -0.24707450425223398, 0.5, 1.0553226028673577, 2.913246921202094, 1.5029344184335343, 2.420987178172286, 1.8538880531275126]
```

If you want them sorted, you can of course sort them before assembling the returned list.

Comment: Did you mix up global `x` and argument `value`?

Comment: that wasn't the question. I've done it already , I need to do it 10M+ times that why I was asking

Comment: @Engine it perfectly answers the question as you asked it... you did not actually ask for performance or stated that you have a working solution.

Comment: @Engine Then you should probably state, that you need an optimized version of it :-)

Comment: For performance use numpy: `lower = np.random.uniform(low, value, num)`

Comment: If you don't care about the distribution you can even create random values where the mean is your `value`. So you can create all the numbers in one numpy call: `np.random.uniform(value-x, value+x, num)`. Depending on your usecase you may need a sort afterwards, which may be even more expensive for large arrays.